# Is it needed to use 'use' if there is 'use base' statement already

Tags: perl, inheritance

I have a module say `Foo.pm`

```
package Foo; 
sub new {
}    
sub SomeMethod {
}
1;
```

Then a subclass,`Foo::Bar` Foo/Bar.pm

```
package Foo::Bar;
use base Foo;
use Foo; 
sub SomeMethod {
}
1;
```

Now do we need to use

```
use base Foo;
use Foo;
```

or just

```
use base Foo;
```

will do both.

Also if we need to use `use Foo;`

What different does it do?

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`use base Module;` will always load the package if needed, but it won't import from it. It's similar to

```
BEGIN {
    require Module;
    push @ISA, 'Module';
}
```

`use Module;`, on the other hand, will import the module's default exports*. It's similar to

```
BEGIN {
    require Module;
    Module->import();
}
```

So the `use Foo;` following `use base 'Foo';` isn't required unless you want to import from the module.

---

* — Technically, it merely calls `import` with no arguments if the module defines such a method. What I described is the normal behaviour of `import` methods.